# Detecting which class to be returned in java

Tags: java

I need to check for an condition and if it is satisfied i need to return a class if it is not satisfied i need to return another class

```
private <T> d(String example) {

        if(example.startsWith("example1"))
            return new example1();
        else if((example.startsWith("example2"))
            return new example2();

    }
```

I am not sure how to return it can u please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a super class or interface for both objects you could return. If you haven´t defined a super class for them, you can still return `Object` and do the not so good `instanceof` validation to know which class has been returned.

Code Example:

```
class SuperClass {
}

class MyClass1 extends SuperClass {
}

class MyClass2 extends SuperClass {
}

private SuperClass myMethod(String parameter) {
    SuperClass sc = null;
    //just trying some code, this could be replaced for your logic
    if (parameter.equals("1")) {
        sc = new MyClass1();
    } else {
        sc = new MyClass2();
    }
    return sc;
}

private void myOtherMethod(String parameter) {
    //some code here...
    SuperClass sc = myMethod(parameter);
    if (sc != null) {
        //securing the upcast...
        if (sc instanceof MyClass1) {
            //logic of MyClass1 instance...
        }
        if (sc instanceof MyClass2) {
            //logic of MyClass2 instance...
        }
    }
    //more logic over here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case supper class or interface of both the class must be same and then return that super class reference from the function.

For example -

```
class SuperClass {
// Variables

// Functions
}

class example1 extends SuperClass{

// Variables

// Functions

}

class example2 extends SuperClass{

// Variables

// Functions

}


private SuperClass d(String example) {

        if(example.startsWith("example1"))
            return new example1();
        else if((example.startsWith("example2"))
            return new example2();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Object getObject(String example) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    if (example.startsWith("example1"))
        return Class.forName("example1ClassName").newInstance();
    if (example.startsWith("example2")) {
        return Class.forName("example2ClassName").newInstance();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But as you noticed this method throws a lot of exceptions so be careful. You classes might have no public default constructors or some classpath issues. It's sensitive and requires cast operation to operate with returned value. The benefit is that you are free of any inheritance/superclass issues and can use any class to be instantiated.

Comment: No need to use reflection for this case. Use reflection wisely and only if you´re handling the object references dynamically.

Comment: Agreed if you are the owner of all classes and can provide inheritance. But this was not clear for me from the question. Even if it's not you always can return 'Object' from the 'myMethod()' in your answer. What's for me I prefer reflection for this kind of cases.